# Aceder phpMyAdmin remotamente

Tags: phpmyadmin

Estou a ter dificuldades em aceder a página externa do phpMyAdmin.
É a primeira vez que estou a tentar aceder pois esta num servidor externo. 
Tem um utilizador que consegue entrar sem nenhuma dificuldade e eu não consigo.

Uso: http://NOMEExemplo.pt/phpMyAdmin

Existe algum campo que de permissões para entrar no phpMyAdmin externo?

Comment: Mas qual é o problema? O que acontece?

Comment: Não acontece nada. Diz que está página não está disponível.

Comment: Eu por exemplo acedo por https://meusite.pt/phpmyadmin/

Comment: é o que estou a tentar fazer e não consigo. 
Para conseguir entrar dessa forma teve que fazer alguma alteração?